# How to link variables from environment.ts file to service.ts file in angular 15

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-web-developer, yahoo-weather-api

I've been coding a weather app using angular 15. I created environment folder using a command but I'm not able to use the declared variables in service.ts file. It shows
Property 'XRapidAPIHostHeaderValue' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
How can I fix it

[my weather.service.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdiyV.png)
[my environment.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvhBS.png)

I need a solution to fix 'Property 'XRapidAPIHostHeaderName' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)' errors that occurs for all the variables declared in environment.ts file

Comment: Have you configured the target-specific file replacements? See: https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements

Comment: And you shouldn't use import referencing `environment.development`. This is an anti-pattern. Instead, you should use file replacements.